# Nginx dockerized accessing host IIS website on a given port

Tags: nginx, docker, windows-10

I'm running docker on windows 10. Some details form docker info

Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5

I need to use nginx as reverse porxy to  web app running under my local IIS(e.g. http://localhost:90)

that's my nginx default.config

```
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name localhost;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.75.1;#works
        #proxy_pass http://10.0.75.1:90;#does not work
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

I'm using the IP 10.0.75.1 to access my host from the container (nginx)
It works as expected if I do not specify the port. 
What should I do/configure to be able to access my host(IIS website) on a specific port?

Comment: what is the 10.0.75.1 ip address? where did that come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746453/how-to-connect-to-docker-host-from-container-on-windows-10-docker-for-windows/40746454#40746454