# How to connect to SQLEXPRESS on host from windows docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I am developing an ASP.NET Core application to be run in Docker.  During development, I would like the container to connect to SQLEXPRESS running on my development machine, which is also my docker host.  However, as best I can tell the container cannot reach the host at all.  I am unable to connect to SQL or ping the host IPs from the container.  I am able to run the app local on my host and connect to SQL Server just fine, so I suspect if I can get it where I can ping the host from the container, I could connect to SQL.

The host has an ip of 10.0.0.5 on the main adapter, and ip of 172.30.96.1 on the "HNS Internal NIC", which I think is the one Docker is using.

To test basic connectivity, I tried to ping from inside the container:

```
docker exec -i containername cmd
c:\app ping 10.0.0.5
Request timed out
c:\app ping 172.30.96.1
Request timed out
```

Based on some similar posts, I have also tried to connect to a "host" network, but this isn't available for this version of docker, apparently.  I suspect this is more for linux:

```
docker run --net="host" ...
network host not found.
```

I also found a similar Windows 10 post which suggested a "transparent" network.  With this network, I couldn't connect in or out:

```
docker network create --driver transparent trans --gateway 10.0.0.1 --subnet 10.0.0.1/16
docker run --net=trans ...
docker exec -i containername cmd
c:\app> ipconfig
IPv4 address: 10.0.205.104
c:\app> ping 10.0.0.5
Request timed out
c:\app> exit
ping 10.0.205.104
Request timed out
```

Here's my docker info:

```
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 10
 Server Version: 17.03.2-ee-5
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
  Log:
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.1593.amd64fre.rs1_release.170731-1934)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 8GiB
 Name: danielsdev5
 ID: XLTN:PBAQ:BU7C:BMR6:O2VJ:DQKQ:P7TY:6QR7:NWEI:GEIF:OFND:ZVFE
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
 Debug Mode (client): false
 Debug Mode (server): false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Which version of Windows OS?

Comment: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746453/how-to-connect-to-docker-host-from-container-on-windows-10-docker-for-windows#