# Docker in Windows server: How to connect tcp applications?

Tags: c#, docker, tcpclient, tcplistener

1) Have tcp-server console application in host system Windows Server 2016

2) Have tcp-client console application in docker container based on windowsservercore

I can't connect from tcp-client to tcp-server.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore 
ADD . /
EXPOSE 9595
ENTRYPOINT ExampleTcpClient.exe
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run -p 9595:9595 --rm mycontainer
```

[How to connect to docker host from container on Windows 10 (Docker for Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746453/how-to-connect-to-docker-host-from-container-on-windows-10-docker-for-windows)
I get Ip 172.18.112.1 by command **ipconfig**, but have error in tcp-client:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.18.112.1:9595
```

I tried several combinations:

tcp_server - 127.0.0.1:9595, tcp_client- 127.0.0.1:9595

tcp_server  - 127.0.0.1:9595, tcp_client- 172.18.112.1:9595

tcp_server  - 172.18.112.1:9595, tcp_client- 172.18.112.1:9595

tcp_server  - 127.0.0.1:9595, tcp_client- 172.17.0.1:9595

tcp_server  - host_static_ip:9595, tcp_client- 172.17.0.1:9595

tcp_server  - host_static_ip:9595, tcp_client- 172.18.112.1:9595

tcp_server  - host_static_ip:9595, tcp_client - host_static_ip:9595

If i start tcp_server in host system and start tcp_client in another machine with config: tcp_server  - host_static_ip:9595, tcp_client - host_static_ip:9595, then it's work (without docker).

Comment: For the container to connect out to the host you need something like `--network=host`. Using `-p` only sets up port forwarding into the container network which is otherwise fully isolated from the host.

Comment: Please check if your docker container is still running with `docker ps`.
Normally a docker container does exit as soon as no process is running anymore.

Comment: Docker is running because tcp client same time try to connect, and I set thread.sleep()

Comment: TypeIA, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746453/how-to-connect-to-docker-host-from-container-on-windows-10-docker-for-windows#comment79498987_40789612       "Your answer does not work for Windows and Mac atm. --net="host" only works for Linux. On Mac you can access host Machine by name docker.for.mac.localhost, on Windows there is no such name and you can get bridge IP address with ipconfig"

Comment: @TypeIA, I try start command in docker container: `ping 172.18.112.1` - it work; `ping static_ip` - it don't work;

Comment: @TypeIA, I intall IIS server and in application i triyed using `WebClient wc= new WebClient(); wc.DonwloadString("http://172.18.112.1/"); wc.DonwloadString("http://static_ip/");` It don't work (error: Unable to connect to the remote server);

Comment: if tcp_client app in docker container and tcp_server app on another vps machine, then they can connect. I haven't idea how do it on one machine, because applications in docker container can't connect to application on host system...

Comment: @kepo4ka OK, I don't have any experience with Docker for Windows or with Windows containers. Sounds like the networking is a bit different. My apologies