# Is anyone else having trouble using host.docker.internal in azure pipelines

Tags: docker-compose, azure-pipelines

It seems to have stopped working recently.
I use docker compose to run some microservices so that unit tests can use them. Some of the microservices talk to each other, so they use a configuration value for the base URL. This is an example of my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  microsa:
    container_name: api.a
    image: *****
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "20001:80"

  microsb:
    container_name: api.b
    image: *****
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "20002:80"
    depends_on:
      microsa:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - ApiUrl=http://host.docker.internal:20001/api/v1/test
```

This works perfectly on my Windows machine docker desktop, but it will not work in Azure Pipelines on either **ubuntu-latest** or **windows-latest**

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Run docker compose for unit tests'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureResourceManagerConnection }}
    azureContainerRegistry: ${{ parameters.acrUrl }}
    dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
    action: 'Run services'
```

When *api.b* attempts to call *api.a*, I get the following exception:

> No such host is known. (host.docker.internal:20001)

Using `http://microsa:20001/...` gives the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (microsa:20001)

I've also tried `http://localhost:20001/...`

I've also confirmed that *microsa* is accessible directly, so there is no errors within that container.

I've also tried running `docker-compose up` via **AzureCLI@2** instead of **DockerCompose@0** with the same results

Comment: `host.docker.internal` is currently only supported by default on Docker Desktop; unless Azure had specific options to support this, I'm not sure how that worked before. That said; is there a reason to publish the ports, and not connect to the other service using the "internal" network by connecting to the other service by its name? Might need to change service-names to not have a `.`?

Comment: Apologies if you saw the previous comment, I was looking at the wrong results (I was looking at the one that was working last month!).
I removed the `.` and tried both `localhost` and `microsa` with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why `http://host.docker.internal:20001` is not working now, even though I'm certain it used to...

However, using `http://microsa/...` (without the port number) does work.

Comment: Might be related? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12673

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue but couldn't use the service dns name because I'm sharing a configuration file between the dependencies and the test project which contains the connection strings for various services defined in the docker-compose file. The test project (which is not running inside docker-compose) needs access to some of those services as well.

To solve it, all I had to do was add a bash script at the start of the pipeline that adds a new record to the hosts file:

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
   echo '127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
   
  displayName: 'Update Hosts File'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me sadly but after a bit of googling and testing adding this to my container worked:

`extra_hosts: - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`