# Prometheus - connect: no route to host. Even though the service is up

Tags: spring, docker-compose, prometheus, spring-actuator

When I access Prometheus targets, one of these targets is getting "state down", even thoug I can access it on my browser ([image]). I am problably missing something. I´d like to know what it is, because I have searched for it for some hours and I can´t find the reason. I even disabled the Windows firewall for a while, but it doesn´t work.

I am using docker and Spring. The Rest services I created are working fine. (myIP is the localhost in the code and in the image).

My docker is configurated as shown bellow.

docker-compose.yml

## Use root/example as user/password credentials

version: '3.8'

services:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.22
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: atendente
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: atendente
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: plano_saude_db
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.21
    container_name: jaeger
    ports:
      - 5775:5775/udp
      - 6831:6831/udp
      - 5778:5778
      - 16686:16686
      - 14268:14268
      - 14250:14250
      - 9411:9411
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.24.1
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command:
      '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
```

prometheus.yml:

global:
scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

```
# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'planosaude-sys'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['<myIp>:8080']
```

Accessing http://myIp:8080/actuator/prometheus I get the following:

```
# HELP jdbc_connections_idle Number of established but idle connections.
# TYPE jdbc_connections_idle gauge jdbc_connections_idle{name="dataSource",} 10.0
# HELP tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions  
# TYPE tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions gauge tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions 0.0
# HELP jvm_memory_max_bytes The maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for memory management
# TYPE jvm_memory_max_bytes gauge jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled
nmethods'",} 1.2288E8 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Survivor
Space",} -1.0 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",}
1.579155456E9 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} -1.0 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",} 5898240.0 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap",id="G1
Eden Space",} -1.0 jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed
Class Space",} 1.073741824E9
jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled
nmethods'",} 1.2288E8
# HELP jvm_threads_peak_threads The peak live thread count since the Java virtual machine started or peak was reset
# TYPE jvm_threads_peak_threads gauge jvm_threads_peak_threads 21.0
# HELP jvm_threads_states_threads The current number of threads having NEW state
# TYPE jvm_threads_states_threads gauge jvm_threads_states_threads{state="runnable",} 9.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="blocked",} 0.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="waiting",} 5.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="timed-waiting",} 6.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="new",} 0.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="terminated",} 0.0
# HELP jdbc_connections_max Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated at the same time.
# TYPE jdbc_connections_max gauge jdbc_connections_max{name="dataSource",} 10.0
# HELP process_uptime_seconds The uptime of the Java virtual machine
# TYPE process_uptime_seconds gauge process_uptime_seconds 2484.248
# HELP logback_events_total Number of error level events that made it to the logs
# TYPE logback_events_total counter logback_events_total{level="warn",} 1.0
logback_events_total{level="debug",} 0.0
logback_events_total{level="error",} 0.0
logback_events_total{level="trace",} 0.0
logback_events_total{level="info",} 15.0
# HELP jvm_classes_loaded_classes The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine
# TYPE jvm_classes_loaded_classes gauge jvm_classes_loaded_classes 12647.0
# HELP jvm_threads_live_threads The current number of live threads including both daemon and non-daemon threads
# TYPE jvm_threads_live_threads gauge jvm_threads_live_threads 20.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds Connection usage time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds summary hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds_count{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds_sum{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds_max Connection usage time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds_max gauge hikaricp_connections_usage_seconds_max{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes Max size of long-lived heap memory pool
# TYPE jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes gauge jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes 1.579155456E9
# HELP jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes An estimate of the total capacity of the buffers in this pool
# TYPE jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes gauge jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes{id="mapped - 'non-volatile memory'",}
0.0 jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes{id="mapped",} 0.0 jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes{id="direct",} 32768.0
# HELP jvm_memory_committed_bytes The amount of memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use
# TYPE jvm_memory_committed_bytes gauge jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled
nmethods'",} 1.1337728E7 jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1
Survivor Space",} 2097152.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Old Gen",} 3.7748736E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 7.0582272E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
'non-nmethods'",} 2555904.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} 2.62144E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class
Space",} 9109504.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled
nmethods'",} 4325376.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_pending Pending threads
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_pending gauge hikaricp_connections_pending{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP tomcat_sessions_alive_max_seconds  
# TYPE tomcat_sessions_alive_max_seconds gauge tomcat_sessions_alive_max_seconds 0.0
# HELP tomcat_sessions_active_current_sessions  
# TYPE tomcat_sessions_active_current_sessions gauge tomcat_sessions_active_current_sessions 0.0
# HELP jdbc_connections_min Minimum number of idle connections in the pool.
# TYPE jdbc_connections_min gauge jdbc_connections_min{name="dataSource",} 10.0
# HELP jdbc_connections_active Current number of active connections that have been allocated from the data source.
# TYPE jdbc_connections_active gauge jdbc_connections_active{name="dataSource",} 0.0
# HELP jvm_threads_daemon_threads The current number of live daemon threads
# TYPE jvm_threads_daemon_threads gauge jvm_threads_daemon_threads 16.0
# HELP jvm_memory_used_bytes The amount of used memory
# TYPE jvm_memory_used_bytes gauge jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled
nmethods'",} 1.1297792E7 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1
Survivor Space",} 1651760.0 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1
Old Gen",} 2.7873792E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 7.0095672E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",}
1357312.0 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="G1 Eden Space",} 1.2582912E7 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 8883800.0 jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap
'non-profiled nmethods'",} 4293632.0
# HELP tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total  
# TYPE tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total counter tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total 0.0
# HELP process_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" for the Java Virtual Machine process
# TYPE process_cpu_usage gauge process_cpu_usage 0.0013668563296602018
# HELP hikaricp_connections_active Active connections
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_active gauge hikaricp_connections_active{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total  
# TYPE tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total counter tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total 0.0
# HELP jvm_buffer_count_buffers An estimate of the number of buffers in the pool
# TYPE jvm_buffer_count_buffers gauge jvm_buffer_count_buffers{id="mapped - 'non-volatile memory'",} 0.0
jvm_buffer_count_buffers{id="mapped",} 0.0
jvm_buffer_count_buffers{id="direct",} 4.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds_max Connection creation time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds_max gauge hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds_max{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds Connection creation time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds summary hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds_count{pool="HikariPool-1",} 10.0
hikaricp_connections_creation_seconds_sum{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.943
# HELP jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total Count of positive increases in the size of the old generation memory pool before GC to after GC
# TYPE jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total counter jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total 1.356288E7
# HELP system_cpu_usage The "recent cpu usage" for the whole system
# TYPE system_cpu_usage gauge system_cpu_usage 0.07962681468188304
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds summary http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",}
1.0 http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",}
2.7254424
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds_max  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds_max gauge http_server_requests_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",}
0.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_timeout_total Connection timeout total count
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_timeout_total counter hikaricp_connections_timeout_total{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_max Max connections
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_max gauge hikaricp_connections_max{pool="HikariPool-1",} 10.0
# HELP jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes Size of long-lived heap memory pool after reclamation
# TYPE jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes gauge jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes 0.0
# HELP jvm_classes_unloaded_classes_total The total number of classes unloaded since the Java virtual machine has started execution
# TYPE jvm_classes_unloaded_classes_total counter jvm_classes_unloaded_classes_total 0.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_idle Idle connections
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_idle gauge hikaricp_connections_idle{pool="HikariPool-1",} 10.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections Total connections
# TYPE hikaricp_connections gauge hikaricp_connections{pool="HikariPool-1",} 10.0
# HELP jvm_gc_pause_seconds Time spent in GC pause
# TYPE jvm_gc_pause_seconds summary jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC",cause="Metadata GC
Threshold",} 1.0 jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of minor
GC",cause="Metadata GC Threshold",} 0.004
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1
Evacuation Pause",} 9.0 jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of minor
GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",} 0.038
# HELP jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max Time spent in GC pause
# TYPE jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max gauge jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max{action="end of minor GC",cause="Metadata GC
Threshold",} 0.0 jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max{action="end of minor
GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",} 0.0
# HELP jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total Incremented for an increase in the size of the (young) heap memory pool after one GC to before the
next
# TYPE jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total counter jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total 2.42221056E8
# HELP hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds Connection acquire time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds summary hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds_count{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds_sum{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds_max Connection acquire time
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds_max gauge hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds_max{pool="HikariPool-1",} 0.0
# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge process_start_time_seconds 1.631847251003E9
# HELP tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total  
# TYPE tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total counter tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total 0.0
# HELP jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes An estimate of the memory that the Java virtual machine is using for this buffer pool
# TYPE jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes gauge jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="mapped - 'non-volatile memory'",} 0.0
jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="mapped",} 0.0
jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="direct",} 32768.0
# HELP system_cpu_count The number of processors available to the Java virtual machine
# TYPE system_cpu_count gauge system_cpu_count 8.0
# HELP hikaricp_connections_min Min connections
# TYPE hikaricp_connections_min gauge hikaricp_connections_min{pool="HikariPool-1",} 10.0
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.planosaude</groupId>
    <artifactId>planosaude-sys</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>planosaude-sys</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I use docker.for.win.localhost, I get the error:

> 'dial tcp: lookup docker.for.win.localhost on 127.0.0.11:53: no such
> host".

I am trying to solve this new error now.

**Solved**

It works if I use *host.docker.internal* instead.

Comment: Are these docker containers running on the same host as `<myIP>:8080`?

Comment: <myIP>:8080 and localhost:9090 ... as you can see in the image.

Comment: That didn't quite answer my question, or maybe I phrased my question poorly. Localhost would refer to the container in that context. I am asking if the server `<myIP>` is also hosting the prometheus container? I want to confirm if the container is trying to make a request directly to the host that it is running on.

Comment: Yes... myIP is also the localhost. I put myIP because I found that it does not accept "localhost" in that case.

Comment: myIP is my IP number... I did not put it in here for security reasons.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Docker for windows. Is myIP the IP of the Docker network interface? If not, try using that IP instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746454/2079781

Comment: @Rickkwa, I read the answer you posted here. If I use docker.for.win.localhost, I get the error 'dial tcp: lookup docker.for.win.localhost on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". I am trying to solve this new error now.

Answer (score 0):

In field `<myip>` you should use `mysql`.

As stated in [Networking in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

If you use `localhost` that refers to the container itself, but inside the prometheus container, only prometheus is running, not the mysql instance.

Job scraping prometheus is working, because prometheus itself is running in localhost.

Comment: I dont get it why MySQL, but it does not work.