# Unable to access web application from robot framework container using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, robotframework

I'm using docker-compose for the web application setup and running robot framework in separate docker container within docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: isp-frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - isp-network
    expose:
      - 3000  
    environment:
      # (while it's applied when TS is compiled)
      # For the frontend can be applied only during the build! 
      # You have to build manually without cache if one of those are changed at least for the prod mode.
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_API=https://localhost:8000/api/v1
      - HTTPS=true
      - SSL_CRT_FILE=/app/dev-cert.dev-pem 
      - SSL_KEY_FILE=/app/dev-key.dev-pem
      - CI=true
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    #  - REACT_APP_ENV=sandbox
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - isp-network
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "test@test.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: dev
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
       - ./pgadmin-config/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - isp-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    container_name: isp-backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    # these ports will be accessible internally and published on the host machine.
    ports:
      - "8000:443"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: > 
      bash -c "pip list && env && exec /start-reload.sh"
    networks:
      - isp-network
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    # These ports will be accessible by other services connected to the same network, 
    # but won't be published on the host machine.
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/.secret/secret.json
      - APP_DB_CONNECTION_STRING=postgresql+psycopg2://test:test@postgres:5432/postgres
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True
      - CORS=https://localhost:3000,http://localhost:3000,https://isp-frontend:3000
      - PORT=443
      - AUTH_ALLOWED_DOMAINS=*
      - AUTH_REDIRECT_URL=https://localhost:3000/login
      # make uvicorn run as SSL/HTTPS
      - UVICORN_SSL_CERTFILE=/app/dev-cert.dev-pem
      - UVICORN_SSL_KEYFILE=/app/dev-key.dev-pem
      - UVICORN_RELOAD_EXCLUDE=env\*,venv\*,env,venv,.gitlab\*,.pytest_cache\*,.scannerwork\*,.secret\*,.vscode
      - UVICORN_RELOAD_DIR=/app/
      # port of uvicorn inside of the container
      - PRE_START_PATH=/app/scripts/alembic-upgrade.sh

  testing:
    container_name: testing
    build:
      context: ./isp-testing
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./isp-testing:/isp-app
    command: > 
      bash -c "/wait
      && mkdir -p /isp-app/tests/report
      && cd /isp-app/tests/ 
      && robot --outputdir "./report/FE_log" --include US24 ."
    networks:
      - isp-network
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend  
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS=frontend:3000
      - WAIT_TIMEOUT=3000
      - WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL=300
      - WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300
      - FRONTEND_URL=https://isp-frontend:3000
      - BACKEND_URL=https://isp-backend:8000/api/v1
      - ROCHE_EMAIL=test@test.com
      - ROCHE_PASS=RJ2ND
      - ROCHE_USERNAME=TEST

volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
    testing:

networks:
    isp-network:
        driver: bridge
```

The frontend and backend service connect using localhost successfully. But the testing service, robot framework fails to connect to frontend service using localhost(https://localhost:3000 and https://localhost:8000/api/v1). It works using service name. We are using service name between frontend and backend and it works fine with localhost. Only in testing service it fails to connect to application using localhost.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried to connect using docker ip, instead of localhost? have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746453/how-to-connect-to-docker-host-from-container-on-windows-10-docker-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve managed to solve this by adding the `network` flag to the `builds` section , the testing docker container can able to access the application using localhost.

```
testing:
    container_name: isp-testing
    build:
      context: ./isp-testing
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: host  # This helps to access the application running in host machine using localhost
    volumes:
      - ./isp-testing:/isp-app
    command: > 
      bash -c "/wait
      && mkdir -p /isp-app/tests/report
      && cd /isp-app/tests/ 
      && robot --outputdir "./report/FE_log" --include US24 ."
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend  
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS=docker.for.win.localhost:3000
      - WAIT_TIMEOUT=3000
      - WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL=300
      - WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300
      - FRONTEND_URL=https://localhost:3000
      - BACKEND_URL=https://localhost:8000/api/v1
```