# how to connect to localhost:9092 from docker container using docker-compose and not using docker bridge

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am running Kafka server on my **local machine** on port 9092.
I  am running a service in **docker container using docker-compose** which needs to send message to kafka server.

I tried writing my producer in service code using 'localhost' and IP as well but both are not working.

Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: A different approach to solve this problem - from a Kafka configuration standpoint, not a Docker configuration - is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57063556/302343

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**With docker-compose:**

Use the network_mode option to allow connection to localhost ports

```
network_mode: "host"
```

**Without docker-compose:**

Use the --net flag to allow connection to localhost ports

```
docker run -it --net=host
```

You can also use --network flag

```
--network="host"
```

According to the official Docker documentation these "give the container full access to local system services such as D-bus and is therefore considered insecure."

Of course if you containerise your service that is running on localhost:9092 then you could run that in a Docker container too and link your two Docker containers together using the --link flag:

```
docker run -t -d myService
docker run -t -d --link myService:myService_ref myOtherService
```

Comment: once he is using `docker-compose` I would suggest to use the `external_links` tag from version 3, instead of using a `docker run`, it would make less changes for him, docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#externallinks

Comment: net=host is the sledgehammer/last resort/not best practices option.

Comment: @GreensterRox , I  am using docker-compose. How can i configure and run it using docker-compose up?

Comment: @ManishKumar Looking at docker-compose --help I'm not seeing an option to specify the 'net' arg. Can you try connecting to the IP address of your host instead from within the container?

Comment: @GreensterRox It got  resolved by putting network_mode: "host" inside docker-compose.yml

Comment: Your answer  is also correct when we run docker without using docker-compose.

Comment: @ManishKumar  - great ! Glad you got it working. I've updated the answer for anyone else who may need help with this.

Comment: This solution works, but then you can only connect to the container afterwards on Linux https://stackoverflow.com/a/52554681/664054

Answer (score 7):

You could fix the IP address of your host and pass this to docker via docker-compose using the 'extra_hosts' option:

Something like:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.123.1
```

Then in docker compose:

```
extra_hosts:
 - "service.localhost:172.16.123.1"
```

Then within the container you should be able to:

```
ping service.localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

Connect from container to local machine. Make IP alias for localhost

```
sudo ifconfig lo:0 172.18.1.1 up
```

Add to docker-compose config service lines

```
extra_hosts:
      - 'local.machine:172.18.1.1'
```

And after container restart it can be used to connect

```
'web-socket-server' => 'ws://172.18.1.1',
```