# Configuring Kafka to accept clients both from inside and outside docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am running Apache Kafka inside a docker network. The container of the Kafka broker is called docker_kafka. What I want is to allow connections from Kafka clients from another docker container as well as from docker host. Port 9092 of the docker_kafka has been mapped to the docker host.

I have been trying `KAFKA_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` environment variables. For example when I use `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092`, then another docker kafka client cannot connect to kafka by `PLAINTEXT://docker_kafka:9092` and vice versa. It does not allow multiple address with same port number and protocol.

Is there a way to allow both type of connections?

Comment: You can do this with DNS on a docker network. Name the container with a DNS hostname you can resolve outside the container to your host IP.  Then inside the container the same name will resolve to the internal address.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean setting up docker DNS and an external DNS. The docker DNS resolves to docker_kafka and external DNS resolves to my host. I think this should work, but this setup is actually for developers so that everyone can start the whole system locally. Still, I can update the host file instead of modifying the external DNS.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure multiple listeners in Kafka. An option `listener.security.protocol.map` allows to use same security protocol multiple times in the listeners config.

Using environment variables:

1.Define the mappings to as many listener aliases as necessary:

```
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER1:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER2:PLAINTEXT
```

2.Then, configure the listeners using the aliases. Sure enough, for this to work each listener needs to listen on its own host+port:

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER1://0.0.0.0:9092,LISTENER2://0.0.0.0:9093
```

3.Configure according advertised listeners. For ex.:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER1://hostname1:9092,LISTENER2://hostname2:9093
```

4.Finally, for the cluster to work it needs to know which listener to use for the communication between the nodes:

```
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER1
```

Note that I only was able to make this configuration work if the listener is declared on the broadcast address (`0.0.0.0`). I attempted to declare the listener to listen on a fixed host name, but this rendered my configuration inoperable (got `connection refused` errors). I would gladly appreciate a comment explaining this part.

I'm not the author of this idea (and not taking the credit for it). I've found this solution in this blog post: https://www.kaaproject.org/kafka-docker/

Kafka configuration documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration (search for `listener.security.protocol.map` option).