# Starting Consul in docker does not expose http ports

Tags: docker, consul

I followed the instructions in  [cosul docker hub documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) to start the server in an Eucalyptus cloud. However other than using local host the Http port is not getting exposed out

```
export  CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG=/root/consul.json
```

From [1](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/)

```
docker run -d --net=host -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' consul agent -server -bind=127.0.0.1 -bootstrap-expect=1
```

Putting bind address as 127.0.0.1 is not ever starting the server; Giving the IP adress, the server is starting but bot accessible out. I tried -P and -p 8500:8500 also. Still not able to connect from another machine.

Note that this machine had a private IP as well as public IP.

So I am guessing that is the reason why -net-host is not starting on the bind address
Still not clear. Two similar threads I found which may explain this

[Docker container doesn't expose ports when --net=host is mentioned in the docker run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586778/docker-container-doesnt-expose-ports-when-net-host-is-mentioned-in-the-docker)

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13914

Comment: why you are not try docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Rishiloyola

```
 docker run -d -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500/tcp -p 8600:53/udp -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"acl_datacenter":"dc1","acl_default_policy":"deny","acl_down_policy":"extend-cache","acl_master_token":"the_one_ring","bootstrap_expect":1,"datacenter":"dc1","data_dir":"/usr/local/bin/consul.d/data","server":true}' consul agent -server -bind=127.0.0.1 -client=0.0.0.0
```

Client from another machine

```
curl 10.X.X.X:8500/v1/catalog/services
{"consul":[]}
```

Edit

If you need to run without ACL for tests

> docker run -d -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500/tcp -p 8600:53/udp -e
>   'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"bootstrap_expect":1,"data_dir":"/usr/local/bin/consul.d/data","server":true}'
>   consul agent -server -bind=127.0.0.1 -client=0.0.0.0 -ui

and

To test

```
 curl -X PUT -d '{"Datacenter": "dc1", "Node": "bing", "Address": "www.bing.com", "Service": {"Service": "search", "Port": 80}}' myip:8500/v1/catalog/register
```

(from https://jlordiales.me/2015/01/23/docker-consul/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not try docker-compose

this is a simple docker.yml file for consul

```
version: '2'
services: 
  consul:
    container_name: consul
    hostname: consul
    image: progrium/consul
    volumes:
      - /data
      - /config
      - ./consul/consul_ui:/ui
    ports:
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
    environment:
    - DOCKER_IP=$DOCKER_IP
    command: -server -bootstrap -data-dir /data -ui-dir /ui
```

Comment: I am not able to see the consul ui from it.