# docker container is active but port is not displayed

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am building a docker image and running it will following command:

```
docker run --name myjenkins -u root -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-volume:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net=host vm31
```

docker container is up and running when i do `docker ps` output is :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
22a92a3b7875        vm31                                                                              "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds
```

why does not it show the port on which this container is running - so i can not reach jenkins on localhost:8080

Comment: Is you container running or restarting? check ` STATUS` columns

Comment: @Ntwobike yes my container status is up as shown in my question and created 4 seconds ago

Comment: check `docker inspect container-id` and the `NetworkSettings`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker container doesn't expose ports when --net=host is mentioned in the docker run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586778/docker-container-doesnt-expose-ports-when-net-host-is-mentioned-in-the-docker)

Answer (score 4):

You are using two conflicting things together:

- `--net=host`
- `-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000`

The first tells the container to use the network stack of the host, the second is the way to bind container ports with host ports. I believe you only want to use the second one.

Comment: myjenkins is a docker container that has docker in it so I had to run it with --net=host

Comment: Ok, this means that you don't have to `publish` any port then. Any active port of your container will be bound to the same port of the host.

Comment: but i had it working before few days having these two together in docker run i want net=host if not rabbitmq will never be reachable

Comment: What I meant in my previous comment is: (1) it's ok to keep `--net=host` (2) remove the `-p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000`

Answer (score 2):

try after removing option --net=host.

Comment: when i take --net=host it is working but my application is a set of container that will not be reachable without rabbitmq that will not be reachable without --net=host

Comment: --net=host means you are using host network and you publish port will not work. https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#goal