# Mongo container is not able to run mongo server

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers

I was trying to build a mongo container from mongo image
the mongo server didnot start

The commands i used were

```
docker pull mongo

docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v $PWD/mongodata:/data/db --network host --name mongodb mongo
```

Then i tested it by entering the container by using

docker exec -it mongodb bash

then when i type "mongo" in the terminal of the container it showed that it was not able to connect to server

Any ideas on what might have went wrong

Comment: Can you tell if the mongod process started or not?

Comment: no i dont think so

Comment: i think the issue is with the volume but i cannot figure out

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug something like this, run it without `-d` to see the errors clearly in the standard output.

Your problem is most likely one of two:

1. The fact that you are mixing `--port` and `--network host`
2. The directory you are mounting to is NFS or otherwise non standard (are you using Vagrant?).

Try this first (without a volume), see if it works:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb mongo
```

If it does, add the the volume, but this time, use a different directory, for example:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 27017:27017 -v /tmp/mongodata:/data/db --name mongodb mongo
```

Also note that I have removed the `--network host` - you [should not mix port exposure and host network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586778/docker-container-doesnt-expose-ports-when-net-host-is-mentioned-in-the-docker). Choose one or the other.

After this, before even trying to connect, confirm it is running:

```
$ docker ps
```

And finally, connect to it either from the host or from within the container:

```
$ docker exec -it mongodb mongo
```

Finally, as another way of experimenting with any docker stack, consider using docker compose. Here is one for your mongo experiments:

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    image: mongo
    ports: ["27017:27017"]

  client:
    image: mongo
    depends_on: [server]
    entrypoint: mongo --host server
```

And now you can just run:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm client
```