# Run Redis on docker network mode host

Tags: docker, redis, redis-cluster, docker-network

I want to run network mode as host for Redis cluster in docker.

The command to execute in the [redis image of docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis), is written as follows.

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

After performing port mapping by giving the -p option as follows:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 --name some-redis redis
```

If you connect to redis-cli, the connection is good.

```
> redis-cli -p 6379

127.0.0.1:6379>
```

If you look at the network with docker container inspect some-redis, the default network mode is bridge.

```
"Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
```

I tried to proceed with the host.

```
docker run --net=host -p 6379:6379 --name some-redis redis
```

```
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
```

If a phrase such as, is displayed, the port is not disclosed.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                            NAMES
6f4edb2c4f8a   redis                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago    Up 4 seconds                                                     some-redis
```

Of course, you can't even connect to redis-cli.

```
> redis-cli -p 6379

Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

[Docker container doesn't expose ports when --net=host is mentioned in the docker run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586778/docker-container-doesnt-expose-ports-when-net-host-is-mentioned-in-the-docker)

Looking at the above question, it seems that the port should be automatically public.

How can I expose ports in network mode host in docker redis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you machine, the `--net=host` only works in linux.
https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

Comment: Oh my goodness.. I was running on wsl. I didn't know it

<pre> is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows,</pre>

Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Happy that helped you. You can accept my answer.